# Get specific objects in API response

Tags: angular, typescript

How to get acces to specific object based on property from API response? In my scenerio i have array of Products (i get it properly from my server), `watchedProducts` class have property `productId` that is the same as `id` in `Product` object. My question is, how iterate properly on that arrays (with the best performance) to get `products`, that `watchedProduct.productId == product.id`?

Code:

```
export class MyProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  watchedProducts: WatchedProduct[] = [];
  products: Product[] = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getWatchedProducts();
  }

  getWatchedProducts(): void {
    this.dataService.getObjects(WatchedProduct).subscribe(result => {
      this.watchedProducts = result.object;
      //get watched product, its work fine
    });

    this.dataService.getObjects(Product).subscribe(result => {
      this.products = ...
      //what to do next? 
      //i want to get that products, where watchedProducts[i].productId == products[i].id          
    });
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have my SQL Server where table `Products` is related to `WatchedProducts` like parent-child. `ProductId` in WatchedProducts is FK for `Id` in Products

`products` looks like this:

[image]

And `watchedProducts`:

[image]

In this scenerio, `Product.id == 8 === WatchedProduct.ProductId == 8`

My question is, how to get `products` array where `watchedProduct.productId == product.Id`?

**EDIT2**

Based on one answer i make that thing:

```
getWatchedProducts(): void {
this.dataService.getObjects(WatchedProduct).subscribe(result => {
  this.errorService.showError(result);
  this.watched = result.object;
});
this.dataService.getObjects(Product).subscribe(result => {
  this.errorService.showError(result);
  this.products = result.object;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.watched.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < this.products.length; j++) {
      if (this.watched[i].productId == this.products[j].id)
        this.watchedProducts.push(this.products[j]);
    }
  }
});
```

}

Sometimes i need refresh browser couple of times to get get respons with products objects (to see what i want to get, sometims it works ok, sometimes i get nothing from that func). Could you tell me, what im doing wrong here?:

Comment: please add what you are getting in result and what is your expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure why you even put 2 array actually. Does `watchedProducts: WatchedProduct[] = [];` and `products: Product[] = [];` even did a different thing? Such as storing different value? If not you don't need to re-iterate them. If yes, how about you use `this.products`=result?

Comment: i edited my post

Comment: @Mukyuu i want to get only `Product` from array, that have same `id` value as `Watchedproduct`. How to filter `products array` to get that item that is related to `watchedproduct`?

Comment: I know that best way is to edit my API Server, but i cant do that. I need to deal with that, what i get right now

Comment: This could result in infiinite nested properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, @michasaucer. When you make two subscribe to two different observables, you can not know wich observable finished first. So you can "join" the two calls in only one.

e.g. you can use forkJoin

```
getWatchedProducts(): void {
    forkJoin(this.dataService.getObjects(WatchedProduct),
             this.dataService.getObjects(Product))
       .subscribe(result=>{
//       in result[0] you has the response to getObject(WatchedProduct)
//       in result[1] you has the response to getObjects(Product)

         this.errorService.showError(result[0]);
         this.watched = result[0].object;

         this.errorService.showError(result[1]);
         this.products = result[1].object;
         for (let i = 0; i < this.watched.length; i++) {
           for (let j = 0; j < this.products.length; j++) {
             if (this.watched[i].productId == this.products[j].id)
               this.watchedProducts.push(this.products[j]);
           }
         }
      })
}
```

See that there are a unique subscribe
NOTE: I not revised your code, just use forkjoin

Comment: looks great, i will check it in a minute

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only one `Product` from array, not all of them. `Product`, that have same `id` value as `Watchedproduct` then you would need to add **`Conditional`** rule such as `if`.

```
this.dataService.getObjects(Product).subscribe(result => {
      //what to do next? 
      //i want to get that products, where watchedProducts[i].productId == products[i].id

      for (let i=0; i<this.watchedProducts.length; i++) {
          if (result[i].productId==this.watchedProducts.id) {
             //do your thing to store it.
          }
      }

});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this not work. You can not expect that you has already read "watchedProduct" when you make read getObject. when you has two observables that depends one from another one, you must use ForkJoin, or switchMap or something more to be sure that you have all the data

Comment: In an example form that answer, sometimes watched products load properly, sometimes i get null from respons. Is it thing that yu mentioned @Eliseo?

Comment: @michasaucer, see my answer